# Angular 4 Injection Token : How it works ? what happens behind the scenes ?

Tags: angular

I just want to know how the Angular 4 Injection Token works and what happens behind the scenes.Here i'm creating token 1 and token 2 with the same name but how it's setting as different value ? Anyone who know about the process,please help me.

```
export class InjectionTokenService {
    private value: string;
    checkInjectionToken(): string {
        const name = 'token';
        const token1 = new InjectionToken<string>(name);
        const token2 = new InjectionToken<string>(name);
        console.log(token1);
        console.log(token2);
        if (token1 === token2) {
         return this.value = 'Both having same token';
        } else {
         return this.value = 'Tokens are not same';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Angular DI by default uses the type as key to register providers or to look up providers for constructor parameters.

InjectionToken is an alternative form of a key that can be used when the type is not enough to uniquely identify a provider. For example if you want to provide 3 configuration values thal all are of type string, then the type us not enough to tell DI which one to inject.

Primitive types are generally not supported as keys for providers.

InjectionToken therefore is just a value that is distinguishable from each other value, to work as a key in a registry.

Comment: That's fine.what exactly happens if we compare this tokens ? token1 === token2 .. how and where the value getting generated differently ? Is the instance getting changed or what ? During equality comparison how its showing "Tokens are not same" ?

Comment: They are constants. References to the same constant (from the same import) are equal, others are not. Actually I'm not sure I understand the question. It uses object identity for equality comparison.